# 404 on Socket.io connect

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i use code from examples of socket.io site and has some problem

My server code (on debian 192.168.5.200)

```
var app = require('express')()
, server = require('http').createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1337);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

My client code (index.html)

```
<script src="http://{host ip}:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://{host ip}:1337');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

i start node server
open in browser http://{host ip}:1337
and... got 404 on socket.io connection

it try to get "/api/1/?t=..." url and got answer by express "Cannot get /api/1/?t=..." with 404 error

Please help me (

Comment: Can you check if http:://{host ip}:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js loads  the JS ?

Comment: You keep writing `http:://`. That's wrong, it should be `http://`. Interestingly, your URL is actually not invalid this way (`:` is URL-safe), but it is pointing at the wrong file. (being relative it'd resolve to `http://your_server/http:://wherever` which isn't what you want)

Comment: socket.is.js loaded as JS file

Comment: sorry "::" wasn't mistake ( it misschar

Comment: Can you remove "::" in this line as well var socket = io.connect('http:://{host ip}:1337');

Comment: Oh, sorry again ( removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your client code to:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on("connect", function() {
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, in order to be able to go to `/api/1...` you need to register the corresponding `app.get`, e.g. as `app.get("/api/*", ...`, which would handle all the connections to `/api/...`. Otherwise it is expected that you will be getting the 404 error.

Comment: See https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client for why. Any chance of accepting the answer if it worked?

Comment: @user3626156 To accept an answer, click the checkmark to the left of the answer and it will turn green, indicating that you accepted the answer.