# How to make socket.io connection in intranet

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a node.js chat web-app. [Here is the code that I'm using](http://www.sdz-files.com/cours/nodejs/super-chat.zip). Running this app, only works on localhost.

How do I to make it work on Intranet, please ?

**EDIT :** On Intranet, to test this. I type on the web browser `http://IPaddressHostChat:8080`.
The web browser gets the web page, but, the exchanged messages are not displayed among computers.

How to fix this please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do your bit for those people you ask for help: put your code on github rather than in a zip. Generally socket.io works equally well without any further configuration on intra and internet

Comment: Use just `io.connect()` without host and port in your html. This will fix it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you refer to a specific host and port in your client's code. Use just `io.connect()` dropping host and port in the html file. See the following for exactly the same issue: [404 on Socket.io connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607451/404-on-socket-io-connect/23609019#23609019)

Comment: That wouldn't work. I can no more send POST requests from the other computer !

Comment: Then look for other errors in your code. This is how `socket.io` official examples are setup. See e.g. https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/public/main.js#L26 Surely if you want to provide host and port to your client, do not type it into your html, but serve it by your server-side application

Comment: @Luciekulza See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886773/socket-io-hardcoded-vs-dynamic-connection-url why what I suggestes should work and if it does not it is just indicative of other problems with your code

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know your host IP address. You can do that by opening **cmd** and type **ipconfig**

Then, you should be able to see your own IP address, usually is 192.168.1.**

Use that IP address for your socket connection.

Make sure your client is on the same intranet as yours. You can check your client connection with your server connection by typing

```
ping <host ip address>
```

or if it doesnt give you a ping or request time out, you may check by typing this in cmd

```
tracert <host ip address>
```

Using this command, you will be able to track which part is stopping your client from connecting to your server!
Usually it might be due to some firewall settings!

I have no problem deploying my websocket using intranet!

Comment: It's working. But, when the two peers connect on that web-app you cannot exchange messages.